# On the Subset of an Open Set

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Say, in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, given any open set $G$ and compact set $K$, can we always find some closed set $F$ such that $G\cap K\subseteq F\subseteq G$?

We know that there exists a chain of compact sets $(K_{i})$ such that 
\begin{align*}
K_{1}\subseteq K_{2}^{\circ}\subseteq K_{2}\subseteq\cdots\subseteq K_{j}^{\circ}\subseteq K_{j}\subseteq\cdots
\end{align*}
and that $G=\displaystyle\bigcup_{j}K_{j}^{\circ}=\bigcup_{j}K_{j}$, but then is it necessarily that some $j$ is such that $G\cap K\subseteq K_{j}\subseteq G$?

The set $G\cap K$ is the intersection of an open set and a closed set, if I am not wrong, this has something to do with locally compactness property, but then what else can we infer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $n=1$, $G=(0,2)$, and $K=[1,3]$; then $G\cap K=[1,2)$, and there is no closed $F$ such that $[1,2)\subseteq F\subseteq(0,2)$.

Comment: It's glad to see that you are in MSE again. Anyway, the question I had in mind was about, under what circumstances we can find a "compact covering" that is not too big that still inside the open set?

Comment: @user284331: Thanks. As long as $K\subseteq G$, there’s no problem: it’s covered by the interiors of the $K_j$, so it’s covered by finitely many of them and hence is a subset of some $K_j$. I don’t think that there’s any reasonable condition that will handle intersections of $G$ with $K\nsubseteq G$ in general, though.

Comment: Thanks profesor. Can you help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640998/find-the-supremum-and-infimum-of-a-set-of-real-numbers